# Passing JSON data to DataTables

Tags: javascript, node.js, datatables

So I can easily pass data to my table when the JSON data is read from a .txt file.

However, when I use ajax to hit an endpoint and return data, I get errors. Can anybody see what's wrong?

```
var table; 

$.ajax({
    url: '../forms/test/get_data',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // This comes back correctly and in the same format as the txt file.
    table = $('#feeds').DataTable( {
           //"ajax": "/javascripts/test/ajax/data/object.txt", 
           "ajax" : function(dataa, callback, settings) {
                callback(data)
            },
            "scrollX" : true,
            "data" : data,
            "columns": [
                {
                    "className":      'details-control',
                    "orderable":      false,
                    "data":           null,
                    "defaultContent": ''
                },
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "status" }
           ]});
});
```

I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined
    at n.fn.init.createdRow (eval at  (jquery-1.12.0.min.js:2), :63:45)" as an error in my console.

Answer (score 0):

User to JSON.parse() method for convert string data to object data like

:  "data" : JSON.parse(data),

try above Code..